# Can't run signed apk on android phone

Tags: android, apk, signed, runtimeexception, osmdroid

I'm trying to create a signed android apk file, this works fine.
I installed the file on my cellphone (Android 2.2) but when I open the application I got this stacktrace in my Logcat:

```
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application net.osmand.activities.OsmandApplication: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: values
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4247)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: values
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at java.lang.ClassCache.callEnumValues(ClassCache.java:637)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at java.lang.ClassCache.getEnumValuesInOrder(ClassCache.java:613)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at java.lang.ClassCache.getEnumValuesByName(ClassCache.java:587)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at java.lang.ClassCache.getEnumValue(ClassCache.java:546)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:177)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at aA.a(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at az.i(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at net.osmand.activities.OsmandApplication.onCreate(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4244)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     ... 10 more
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: values
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:308)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     at java.lang.ClassCache.callEnumValues(ClassCache.java:633)
08-23 13:58:55.271: E/AndroidRuntime(3643):     ... 19 more
```

When I ran the apk from Eclipse on my device it ran fine. Also send the apk to a friend and he also had the apk running fine (build by eclipse the on in the bin directory).

Can anybody point me in the right direction?
I believe I can be missing some libraries but I would find this strange because when running it from eclipse it works fine. But like I said I'm a noob!

Comment: It looks like your application requires reflection to work, and it looks like your application has been processed with ProGuard. In that scenario, you need to be careful about restricting what ProGuard obfuscates otherwise your reflection will fail.